# Remove or disable ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, scriptmanager

I have a page where I list several items. Next to each item there is a icon that is linked to the current page, and sends along the item id.

What I do when the page reloads, is I check for the id and if it is there, I delete the item.

After that, I register a popup to fire using `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` (call it popup A).

The problem is, that if I now add a new item using my add new textbox and button, and then register another script using `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` (popup B) , the popup A is still fired as the url still contains the ID of the item I previously deleted??

Does anyone know how to disable/remove that popup A `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` so it wont fire again?

Comment: after 12 question you should know how to answer, please add your code

Comment: Didnt think you would need code for that, its a very straight forward question. But sure, I can add it.